# Create abstract class or implementation with lambda's in constructor?

Tags: java, lambda, abstract-class

I noticed with functions there is now an alternative solution where previously only an abstract class/interface would make sense.

For example:

```
public abstract class AbstractFallbackStrategy {

    public boolean shouldDoFallback(Exception e, Result r) {
        if (isException()) return true;
        if (isEmptyResult()) return true;
        if (isInvalidResult(r)) return true;

        return false;
    }

    protected abstract boolean isInvalidResult(Result r);
}
```

Alternatively, one can now write:

```
public class FallbackStrategy {
    private final Function<Result, Boolean> validResultClassifier;

    public FallbackStategy(Function<Result, Boolean> validResultClassifier) {
        this.validResultClassifer = validResultClassifier;
    }

    public boolean shouldDoFallback(Exception e, Result r) {
        if (isException()) return true;
        if (isEmptyResult()) return true;
        if (validResultClassifier.apply(r)) return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm leaning towards the latter solution as it doesn't force the user to make a subclass.  Are there any other pro/cons?

Comment: Please don't use `Function<Result, Boolean>`. Use `Predicate<Result>` instead.

Comment: @MikhailProkhorov can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Predicate is nicer here as it returns a boolean already.

Comment: @StackFlowed, `Function<Result, Boolean>` actually has three possible return values: `Boolean.TRUE`, `Boolean.FALSE` and `null`, because `(result) -> null` is entirely valid `Function` implementation. In code example there is a potential NPE at line where `valueResultClassifier.apply` called. That whole slew of problems does not come up if you use `Predicate<Result>`, since that returns either `true` or `false` primitives and has clearer signature.